# Web form for creating custom filters with boolean logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean-logic

I have a Rails application in which I'd like a user to be able to create custom boolean combinations from a list of categories, which is itself dynamically loaded.  For example, if I have the categories `foo` `bar` and `baz`, I would like the user to be able to select `(foo AND bar) OR baz` or `foo OR baz` or any other logical combination of those categories.  The most common use case I anticipate is something like `(a OR b OR c) AND (d OR e OR f) AND (g OR h)`; that is, a conjunction of several disjunctions.

The results would then be stored in some data structure which could be later used as a filter.  Ideally this would all be done through a graphical interface, rather than having the user construct the boolean logic in text.

Before I attempt to implement this myself, is there a library that I can pull in that already implements this or something similar?  Or something open-source that could get me part of the way there, and that I could fork and modify?

Comment: I think this could be successfully implemented using a form, select_tags for the category selection AND check_tags to mark if active or not. Submitting the form and storing the data in your DB table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a **Boolean Retrieval** with four ways to select a given category:

1. not selected
2. positive selected (**+** prefix; category is mandatory)
3. negative selected (**-** prefix in Google search; category must not occur)
4. selected (no prefix)

Not in `ruby-on-rails` but probably easy to translate from `c#`:

```
    public bool IsMatch(string s)
    {
        s = s.ToLower();

        bool ret = ((negWords.Count == 0) || !hasMatchInSet(s, negWords, true))
           && ((posWords.Count == 0) || hasMatchInSet(s, posWords, false))
           && ((words.Count == 0) || hasMatchInSet(s, words, true));

        return ret;
    }

   private bool hasMatchInSet(string s, HashSet<string> setOfWords, bool breakOnFirstMatch)
    {
        int matches = 0;
        bool ret = false;

        foreach (string w in setOfWords)
        {
            if (s.IndexOf(w, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                matches++;

                if (breakOnFirstMatch)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        ret = (breakOnFirstMatch && (matches > 0)) || (matches == setOfWords.Count);

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will handle any expression of the form `(a OR b OR ...) AND c AND ... AND ~d AND ~e`.  So it's not quite flexible enough to handle something like `(a OR b OR c) AND (d OR e OR f`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It would be ideal to have a full (possibly nested) Boolean expression with AND / OR / NOT operators and brackets. But the drawback is, this would complicate matters for the end-user. You might want to have a look at how `Excel` allows the user to specify data filters.